# Backward =?= зворотне

Tags: переклад

Часто бачу переклад слова *backward* як *зворотне*. Наприклад,

- [Зворотна сумісність](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
- [Лампа зворотної хвилі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96)
- [Зворотний вивід/міркування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4)

І у словниках:

> backward [ˈbækwɘd] a
> зворотний *(про рух);*
> <sub>Великий англо-український словник 2011 (Є.І. Гороть, Л.М. Коцюк, Л.К. Малімон, А.Б. Павлюк.)</sub>

> backward = ['bækwəd] обе́рнений, зворо́тний || наза́д, у зворо́тному на́прямі
> <sub>Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010 (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)</sub>

А як на мене, то *зворот-н-ий* це той, який можна *завернути*.

Навіть у тому ж словнику Мейнаровича і Кратко бачимо:

> irreversible change = незворо́тна [необоро́тна] змі́на

І подібним чином [у багатьох інших](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD*&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on). То виходить, що цей переклад *backward* це історична помилка?